# How to change button's size in checkbox

Tags: android, button, checkbox, size

I tried to change Button in Checkbox by using png file, but the image was too big and it made the Button too big.

I want to change the Button's size to 20dp.
Then I set layout_width and layout_height in CheckBox, but it didn't solve the problem.

Could you please teach me how to change the size?

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:text="New CheckBox" 
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:button="@drawable/my_check_box"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

my_check_box.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_normal" />
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_selected" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Just a heads up, buttons don't scale like images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the related drawable for it

```
<CheckBox 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="new checkbox" 
android:background="@drawable/my_checkbox_background"
android:button="@drawable/my_checkbox" />
```

This link having good example
[Custom Checkbox](http://www.anddev.org/tutorial_change_look_of_checkbox-t4553.html)